# Getting value from an object with property name as a variable

Tags: php

Quick Question

Lets say I have

```
$colname = 'offer_id';
```

and then I want to get a value from an object with the property name like $colname

```
echo $object->$colname;
```

Usually to do a variable on the fly, I would do **$object->${$colname}** but its not working

Any one can help ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Maybe this will help $object is a an object generated from Wordpress while in a loop.... I tried all your methods but none work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be:

```
$object->$colname
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access properties dynamically like this:

```
$object->{$colname};
```